# How do I save a model using @tensorflow/tfjs-node v2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, tfjs-node

I am struggling to get the save handler to work for saving my model. I've looked through all of stack overflow and GitHub, but no dice.

Ahhh help!!!! lol
Thanks a bunch ahead of time!!! :)

Here is my model code:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ 
   units: 36,
   inputShape: [13]
}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ 
   units: 36, 
   activation: 'relu'
}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ 
   units: 1, 
   activation: 'sigmoid'
}));
    
model.compile({
   optimizer: 'adam',
   metrics: ['accuracy'],
   loss: 'meanSquaredError',
});

await model.fit(xs, ys, {
    epochs: 100
}).then(info => {
    console.log('Accuracy', info.history.acc);
});
await model.save(localhost())
```

Here is my `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^2.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.695.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"
  }
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError: Cannot find any save handlers for URL
```

Comment: try `model.save('file://my-model');`

Comment: That did not work either when I initially had the issue, or I would not have resorted to asking the question on here.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue,
Try this `model.save('file://model-name');`